# How to authenticate Hotmail in Android?

Tags: android

In my app I need to get Gmail, Yahoomail and Hotmail contacts. I got Gmail and Yahoo mail contacts but I don't have any idea how to authenticate for Hotmail.

I got the Gmail authentication and contact details through [this link](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-oauth-full-example-with-source.html). I couldn't find any information about hotmail authentication. Is it possible to authenticate Hotmail with an Android application? And how?

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
It appears that my information on stating that there is no Live Id authentication API may well have been obsolete. I ran across this Microsoft site when double checking: [Live Connect Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live).

Answer (score 0):

How about [Live Connect Hotmail (contacts and calendars)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535)

This is the section about using the API is android apps.
[MSDN Live Connect: Android Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh875196.aspx)